# I can't save the response of a request request in node.js

Tags: node.js, api, request, jwt

I created a login function that receives the mail and the pass, to receive the `jwt`. I have tried that the function returns the `jwt` but I have not succeeded.

This is the method that I have developed, it has a post request that sends the `mail` and `pass` parameters. in the `resp` variable I try to save the request response, but when invoking the function it prints :

> undefined.

```
login(mail, pass) {
  var options = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'url': 'https://inventario.demos.adlnetworks.com/api/login',
      'headers': {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ "email": mail, "password": pass })
  };
  var resp;
  var req = request(options, function(error, response) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
      resp = response.body;
  });
  return resp;
}
```

Comment: can you show how and where you invoke this function? also some details about your package.json file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "request" is an async function. You can't do this

```
var resp;
var req = request(options, function(error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    resp = response.body;
});
return resp;
```

Because "resp" always be undefined. You would need to do something like this

```
var resp;
var req = request(options, function(error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    return response.body;
});
```

But it wont work for you.
**The short and easy solution is** change the library to make http request, and use "async" and "await" to use easily async functions.

For example:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

async function main(){
    const data = await login();
    console.log(data);
}

async function login(){

    const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    const data = {
        title: 'foo22222',
        body: 'ba222r',
        userId: 1
    };

    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        }
    });
    const json = await response.json()
    return json;
}


main();
```

In this case i use "*node-fetch*" library and consume a backend (in login function) that create a post and return its response.

Comment: Thanks Agustin, please how can I save the jwt value for use in the next request?